# If a letter is signed 'Le Directeur de votre banque', is it understood that that person is male, and should be addressed accordingly?

Tags: genre

I think the title sums it up, but if a letter is signed literally (and therefore, rather generically)  'Le Directeur de votre banque', is it understood that that person is male, and should be addressed accordingly?

Comment: Yes, a lady is *Directrice*

Comment: Such a letter might often be signed with the neutral and more friendly *Votre responsable d'agence*.

Comment: Please also bear in mind that it may be a marketing letter sent to all customers. In that case, the signature refers to the function more than to the person, so the template may use the masculien-but-use-as-neutral *directeur* for all directeurs/trices.

Comment: What a can of worms I've opened; I'll reply to one of the clerks instead... and accept the answer that most accords with my prejudices...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily.

While there is an equivalent word for the female genre ("directrice"), because of the existing gender bias in the professional world, many women choose to continue to use the male equivalent instead.

Reference: https://www.eveprogramme.com/3008/madame-le-directeur-ou-madame-la-directrice-les-resultats-de-notre-consultation/

Comment: There is no consensus in France for the time being as far as I know. For every article like that you cited, there is also a supporter of the 'féminisation' (which to be honest sounds more logical to my no native ears). Bear in mind that formes like auteure, docteure did exist in the past. https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2019/02/28/autrice-le-feminin-qui-genait-tant-lacademie-francaise-est-tout-sauf-un-neologisme_a_23680379/

Comment: "There is no consensus in France for the time being as far as I know." Isn't there an official body that defines the meaning and usage of words in the French language? What's their position on the matter?

Comment: @nick012000 Hopefully, there is no authority able to define the meaning or usage of French. That's just something that evolves on its own. The Académie française which I believe your are thinking about has no legal authority to impose anything, it just provides advice and recommendation. Even if it had any authority, it would be restricted to France anyway, not the whole French speaking community, and for a rule to be enforced, there should be a law but no such law exists.

Comment: Note that the very conservative *Académie française* has recently made an opening on this topic, as it finally acknowledges language has evolved. Ironically, it virtually aligns on some official recommandations widely accepted and used in Switzerland, Quebec, and Belgium, and that it had (quite arrogantly IMHO) fought against for years.

Comment: @Dimitris, if there is no consensus, then a letter signed "Le Directeur" doesn't necessarily imply that the person is a male and should be addressed accordingly (which is the question I was answering).

Answer (score 0):

La situation reste encore un débat en France.

[BIEN ÉCRIRE AU TRAVAIL : Orthographe et écriture en contexte professionnel](https://bien-ecrire.fr/feminisation-metiers/#:%7E:text=Si%20on%20respecte%20strictement%20le,supportent%20d%27%C3%AAtre%20appel%C3%A9es%20directrices.)

> La féminisation des métiers comme celle des fonctions reste un débat
> en France. La parité a du mal à avancer dans un pays où la langue
> reste un «trésor national» avec une vestale attitrée : l’Académie
> française. Et force est de reconnaître que l’Académie française ne se
> laisse guère influencer par la féminisation de pans entiers de la
> société, notamment du côté des entreprises et de la vie publique.
>
> Et force est de reconnaître que l’Académie française ne se laisse
> guère influencer par la féminisation de pans entiers de la société,
> notamment du côté des entreprises et de la vie publique.
>
> Ainsi, alors que la langue courante admet sans problème les mots comme
> : auteure, écrivaine, ingénieure, professeure, procureure, chercheure.
>
> L’Académie française considère quant à elle que ces formes de
> féminisation «sont contraires aux règles ordinaires de dérivation et
> constituent de véritables barbarismes.» Selon elle, la règle est
> d’utiliser un déterminant au féminin (la, cette, une,…) avec un nom
> qui reste invariable : une écrivain,
> une professeur,
> une ingénieur.
>
> Précision d’importance ! Dans ce cas, écrivain, professeur et
> ingénieur ne sont pas au masculin mais au «masculin à valeur
> générique», ou encore au «masculin non marqué». La meilleure illustration de l’usage de ce masculin est celle de Madame le secrétaire perpétuel de l’Académie française.
>
> Quand je pense qu’avant d’écrire ce billet, je ne savais même pas
> qu’il existait un «masculin à valeur générique».  En même temps, un
> masculin à valeur générique peut rendre une phrase assez savoureuse :
>
> Le gendarme s’est mariée en robe blanche. Le chirurgien s’est sentie
> mal à l’aise. Le capitaine a accouché d’un beau garçon.
>
> **Mais ça, c’était avant**… Avant le guide»Femme, j’écris ton nom… : guide
> d’aide à la féminisation des noms de métiers, titres, grades et
> fonctions» publié par la Documentation française en 1999…
>
> Et surtout avant sa remise au goût du jour en octobre 2014 du fait
> d’un «Madame le président», sciemment adressé à la vice-présidente de
> l’Assemblée nationale.
>
> **Hasard ou coïncidence, à peine trois ans après cet incident
> linguistique très fortement médiatisé, c’est une circulaire qui impose
> l’usage des règles de féminisation des grades et fonctions. Ainsi,
> «lorsqu’un arrêté est signé par une femme, l’auteure doit être
> désignée, dans l’intitulé du texte et dans l’article d’exécution,
> comme “la ministre”, “la secrétaire générale” ou “la directrice”». De
> même, «s’agissant des actes de nomination, l’intitulé des fonctions
> tenues par une femme doit être systématiquement féminisé».**
>
> La référence pour les règles de féminisation à appliquer est le guide,
> «Femme, j’écris ton nom ».»

Selon cet article, c'est bien évidement **Directrice** pour une dame.

Comment: You focus on the debate but the OP is asking for actual usage. The fact is there are still women who would use *Directeur*.

Comment: Il y a toujours débat, mais l'Académie française a (enfin..) adopté une position moins conservatrice et prescriptive assez récemment (2019): https://www.lemonde.fr/societe/article/2019/02/28/l-academie-francaise-se-resout-a-la-feminisation-des-noms-de-metiers_5429632_3224.html